# How to allow user to select page template from front end?

Tags: page-template

I have post templates ready... I want the user to be able to select the post template from the front end form?

Is there any method or some one could guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_templates/ ?

Comment: exactly!! .please add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `get_page_templates` function. See codex : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_templates/

```
get_page_templates(null, 'your_post_type');
```